# telegram answercallbackquery browser syntax

Tags: google-chrome, telegram, telegram-bot

To get an understanding of telegram-bot syntax I throw a telegram-cli in a chrome browser. I see on a phone what happens and in the browser the response.
Im stuck on a response to an callback answer from an online keyboard button click.

These are the steps:

**Send an online keyboard --> this works**

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=
<chat_id_nr>&text=How%20are%20you&reply_markup=
{"inline_keyboard":k[[{"text":"Fine","callback_data":"great"}],
[{"text":"fine1","callback_data":"great1"},
{"text":"fine2","callback_data":"great2"}]]}
```

Hit an key on the online keyboard.

Get an response back in the browser, like this:

```
{
ok: true,
result: [
{
update_id: **********,
callback_query: {
id: "10665788123459204304",
from: {
id: *********,
```

--> etc
4. Now I want to send an answercallbackquery as mentioned in `https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery"`
When I send:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot>/answerCallbackQuery?
{[{"callback_query_id":"10665788123459204304", "text"=ok, "show_alert"=true}]}
```

Got this answer:

```
{
ok: false,
error_code: 400,
description: "Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID"
}
```

And yes I know that you have to answer in 15 seconds after inline keyboard button click.

I know it is a small thing for the expert but for me Im pulling my hairs out.

Thanks in advance. (bold head, by now)

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this must be the answer:

https://api.telegram.org/bot(bot.token)/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=1066578811231371872

The answer has to be send back in a few seconds. I dit copy/pased within 10 seconds but that seems to be to long.

Putting it all together in a bash script, answered it in aan few seconds and that was all. The solution can be so close.